# Invalid token or unexpected token when importing bulma when using nextjs

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, bulma

I'm trying to  use `bulma` with `next.js`, but I keep getting the following error `Invalid token or unexpected token 
 "../node_modules/bulma/css/bulma.css:2" @-webkit-keyframes spinAround {` which is the very first line inside the `bulma.css`.

Here is my `next.config.js` file with the `webpack` configuration. Am I missing something?

```
const path = require("path");
const glob = require("glob");

module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, { dev }) => {
    config.module.rules.push(
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          { loader: 'css-loader', options: { importLoaders: 1 } }
        ]
      }
    )
    return config;
  }
}
```

Comment: have you got `.babelrc` ?

Comment: @Aaqib yes I do, here it is: 

`{
  "presets": [
    "next/babel"
  ],
  "ignore": []
}`

Comment: `npm install --save-dev babel-preset-stage-0 babel-preset-es2015` and then add it to presets inside `.babelrc` like `{presets: ['stage-0','es2015', 'react','next' ]} }`

Comment: @Aaqib, still the same problem. I think it has to be a problem with the `css-loader` or one of them `Syntax Error: .../node_modules/bulma/bulma.sass:2
@charset "utf-8"
^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token


 @ ./node_modules/bulma/css/bulma.css 4:14-124 18:2-22:4 19:20-130
 @ ./node_modules/reactbulma/lib/components/index.js
 @ ./sections/hero.js
 @ ./pages?entry
 @ multi ./pages?entry`